# Using variable inside a Hash as a key to another Hash

Tags: ruby

I have some data to sort as an array in the form `['a1', 'b321', 'a33', 'c', ...]`.
I want to put all the 'aN' into `sorted_data[:a]` etc.
The code below loops through the data, and correctly runs the regexp on them.
What it doesn't do is put them in the right place - `sorted_data[filter[:key]]` is null.
How do use `filter[:key]` as a key to `sorted_data`?
Thanks.

```
sorted_data = { a: Array.new,
                b: Array.new,
                c: -1 }

filters = [{ re: /^a\d+$/, key: 'a' },
           { re: /^b\d+$/, key: 'b' },
           { re: /^c$/,    key: 'c' }]

['a1', 'b321', 'a33', 'c', 'b', 'b1'].each {|cell|
  filters.each {|filter|
    if cell.match(filter[:re])
      puts "#{cell} should go in #{filter[:key]}" + '....[' + sorted_data[filter[:key]].to_s + ']....' 
      break
    end
  }
}
```

The output of the above is

```
# a1 should go in a....[]....
# b321 should go in b....[]....
# a33 should go in a....[]....
# c should go in c....[]....
# b1 should go in b....[]....
```

Comment: Maybe because `:a != 'a'` ?

Comment: Could you be more helpful?

Comment: `sorted_data` has symbol keys (`:a, :b, :c`), `filters` define keys as strings (`"a", "b", "c"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the program below produces the desired output:

```
l = ['a1', 'b321', 'a33', 'c', 'b', 'b1']
sorted_data = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
l.each do |item|
  first_char = item[0].to_sym
  sorted_data[first_char].push item
end

puts sorted_data
```

Output:

```
{:a=>["a1", "a33"], :b=>["b321", "b", "b1"], :c=>["c"]}
```

Comment: Well, what I need to do is more complicated, I simplified to ask the question - I do need the RegExp. But thanks, your answer showed me what I was doing wrong - I needed the to_sym!

Comment: Oh, ok... I thought you were using the regex only to identify each array element. Glad I could help